# Does it make sense to use OAuth for a native desktop app that owns the resources it uses?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

We have a native Windows desktop app that uses resources that we control on behalf of our customers. In the vein of not rolling our security infrastructure I am wondering if it makes sense to use an OAuth library / framework like IdentityServer (our frontend and backend stacks are .NET based with ASP.NET Core on the backend).

But from what I have read OAuth is all about giving an application access to resources that the users owns that are managed and controlled by another party without exposing the user's security credentials to the application.

Given the application is from our point of view "trusted" it seems more straight forward for the application to capture the password directly from the user and obtain an access token (e.g. bearer token) from directly from the back end rather then redirecting the user to the web browser.

Management of authorization levels for various resources is something we need to take care of robustly, as we will have multiple applications and users which will need configurable access levels to different types of resources, so I don't really want to be rolling our own solution for this.

We also want the ability for users to remain logged for indefinite periods of time but to be able to revoke their access via a configuration change on the back end.

Should we be using a different type of framework to help ensure our implementation is sound from a security point of view? If so please any suggestions of suitable technology options would be most helpful.

Alternatively, is there a OAuth flow that makes sense in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" might help with your problem.

In the short term, the use of oauth may not seem very different from the normally "username password + rbac" based model, but the benefits may come in terms of scalability later on, for example when single sign-on needs to be implemented, or when it comes to the need to provide service interfaces to third parties.